# Shopfiy Locale Selector form

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I am in the process of adding a locale selector to my shopify theme. Basically, i need to have the form auto submit on selection, rather than the user make the selection from the dropdown, then press submit. How would I edit this code to make that happen?

I would remvove the submit button alltogether!

```
{% form 'localization' %}
  
<select name="country_code">
    
{% for country in localization.available_countries %}
      
<option value="{{ country.iso_code }}"
        
{%- if country == localization.country %} selected="selected"{% endif %}
      
>
        
{{ country.name }} ({{ country.iso_code }}) - {{ country.currency.symbol }}
      
</option>
    
{% endfor %}
  
</select>
  
<input type="submit" value="Update">
{% endform %}
```

Shopify documentation on this is here: https://shopify.dev/themes/internationalization/multiple-currencies-languages?shpxid=400ba4ec-D0ED-488B-F8D1-3B448EF5D236

Thanks all!

Comment: you need to use jQuery or javascript to submit the form when a select change event occured.

Comment: Read more about the change  event of jquery [here](https://api.jquery.com/change/)